# Numpy row wise masking

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which has NaN values in some locations.

```
>>> d1
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,  nan,   4.,   5.,  nan,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  nan,  12.,  13.,  nan,  15.],
       [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  nan,  20.,  21.,  nan,  23.],
       [ 24.,  25.,  26.,  nan,  28.,  29.,  30.,  31.],
       [ 32.,  33.,  34.,  35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.],
       [ 40.,  41.,  42.,  43.,  44.,  45.,  46.,  47.],
       [ 48.,  49.,  50.,  51.,  52.,  53.,  54.,  55.],
       [ 56.,  57.,  58.,  59.,  60.,  61.,  62.,  63.]])
```

I want to make **a mask** which will make entire row as `False` value if NaN value present in that row. Like below.

```
>>> mask
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

I tried to apply mask like below But It didnt work.

```
mask = NaN not in d1[,:]
```

Any one can help me to figure this out ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are few approaches -

```
np.repeat(~np.isnan(d1).any(1,keepdims=1),d1.shape[1],axis=1)
~np.isnan(d1).any(1,keepdims=1)*([True]*d1.shape[1])
np.tile(~np.isnan(d1).any(1,keepdims=1),d1.shape[1])
np.broadcast_to(~np.isnan(d1).any(1,keepdims=1), d1.shape)
np.broadcast_to(~np.isnan(d1).any(1), d1.shape).T
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```
mask = lambda x: False if numpy.nan else True
array_mask = numpy.vectorize(mask)
masked_d1 = array_mask(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d2 = np.asarray([x for x in d1 if not np.isnan(x.sum())])
```

using list comprehension (this removes rows you with NaNs, and doesn't replace them with False as it's an array of floats)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [numpy.ma.mask_rows()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.mask_rows.html) from the numpy.ma module.